# Redirecting to another domain using .htaccess

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect

The domain name on one of my websites is changing today and I need to make sure my traffic doesn't drop off. All of the content and URL structures have remained the same.

What I basically need is a command that will perform the following redirects:

```
www.mysite.com/page1  ---->  www.mynewsite.com/page1
www.mysite.com/page2  ---->  www.mynewsite.com/page2
www.mysite.com/page3  ---->  www.mynewsite.com/page3
```

...etc etc

What is the simplest way to achieve this? Should I use .htaccess or edit my apache config file?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Using mod_alias you can do:

```
RedirectMatch 301 ^/(.*)$ http://www.mynewsite.com/$1
```